How far ahead of the average last freeze date is it safe to flood buried irrigation pipe?
I have 1.25" black poly buried at a depth of 18" running a 600 foot span under lawn, and coming up on 1" stainless steel risers into spigots at several locations in the yard. The entire system is connected an external house spigot. The system is currently dry and winterized.
The average last freeze date (32 deg) in my zone (5a) is May 8, and the average last hard freeze (28 deg) is Apr 25.
My question is: must I wait until May 8 to flood the pipes, or will heating from the earth and connected water column safely prevent any damage to the system as early as Apr 25? These last freeze/frost dates touch those temperatures only for a few hours of course. Given that the majority of this system is underground, I'd have to think it'd resist freezing if air temps dropped to 28 deg for a couple hours.
Thoughts? What about the risers/spigots that are above ground? Will the connected water column that comes from below ground give them some protection too?

The black poly parts don't care, they stretch enough that freezing is not an issue for them. Being buried 18" they probably won't freeze anyway.
The joints and the metal parts are what fails with freezing, and since you have metal parts sticking above ground, you'll be better off waiting until after your last freeze date, unless a long range forecast you trust (which are notoriously unreliable past a few days) assures you freezing is not likely this year.
Heat won't be coming up in any useful amount from the water in the pipes - see "why ice forms on the top of ponds" - once the water hits 34°F it's at maximum density, and as the top part gets colder than that it rises, stays up in the exposed pipe, and freezes.
If the spigots are frost-proof (self draining) and turned off to self drain, then it would likely not be a problem, as all the water would be 18" underground with the poly pipes. If it's a pipe with a normal hose bib on top, it would be a shame to damage it when you could wait another week or two and not damage it.
Alternatively, if you make the system and valving in such a way that blowing the risers clear is easily done, you could simply clear the above ground parts of water when you have a prediction of freezing weather in late spring or early fall.
Or you might choose running it overnight as hard as you can to mist crops in the hopes of preventing freeze damage, as some folks do for some crops. Not useful (or needed) for grass, but you didn't specify what you were irrigating.

Thank you, very helpful
